# Get number of users in voice channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am rewriting the music portion of my [friends discord bot](https://top.gg/bot/629799045954797609). I am trying to figure out how to get the number of users in the voice channel of the person who executed the command. I have looked everywhere but I can't seem to find it or its usage.
Right now I am using the following:

```js
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    
  if (!message.member.roles.cache.find(role => config["dj_role"] === string.toLowerCase(role.name))) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_GUILD' || 'MANAGE_ROLES' || 'ADMINISTRATOR')) {
        if (!message.member.id == message.guild.ownerID) {
            let count = 0;
            count += voiceChannel.members.size;
            if (count > 3){
                return message.channel.send(client.msg["rejcted_dj"].replace("[ROLE_DJ]", config["dj_role"]));
            }
        }
    }
}
  if (!message.member.voice.channel){return message.channel.send(client.msg["music_channel_undefined"])}
//play music part
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pretty close. You already got the voice channel of the command author:

> ```js
> if (!message.member.voice.channel){return message.channel.send(client.msg["music_channel_undefined"])}
> ```

You can use the [`VoiceChannel.members.size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) to get how many members are in the channel.

Here's an example:

```js
const GuildMember = new Discord.GuildMember(); // This shall be the command author.

if (GuildMember.voice.channel) {
    console.log(GuildMember.voice.channel.members.size);
};
```