# Is there any way for me to detect when there are no users in a voice channel and then disconnect(Discord.js)

Tags: discord, discord.js

I would like to know of a way to get the amount of users in a voice channel, preferably using the voiceStateUpdate listener. I want to make it so that my bot will disconnect if left alone in a voice channel for a certain period of time. I've tried checking whether or not someone leaves but that will disconnect regardless of how many people are in the voice channel. Is there a method to check the amount of people in a vc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`VoiceChannel.members.size`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members) to get the member count in a channel. Like:

```js
let VC = await client.channels.cache.get("1000000000000001");
if(!VC){
    return(message.channel.send("channel inaccessible"));
}
MemberCount = VC.members.size;
//Might need members.cache.size;
if(MemberCount <= 1){ //Only the bot in vc
    VC.leave();
    //Leaves if the bit is the only user in vc
}
```

You might put it in a `setInterval` too

```js
let VC = await client.channels.cache.get("1000000000000001");
if(!VC){
    return(message.channel.send("channel inaccessible"));
}
setInterval( () => {
    MemberCount = VC.members.size;
    //Might need members.cache.size;
    if(MemberCount <= 1){ //Only the bot in vc
        VC.leave();
        //Leaves if the bit is the only user in vc
    }
}, 5000);
```

Source: [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=members)
Also check this out [Get number of users in voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63758261/get-number-of-users-in-voice-channel)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly, my bot now disconnects and deletes the server queue, I had been searching for hours and couldn't find this